# How to change the text property of labels that have similar design names in a loop?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have several labels within a table design layout on my form. I want to change the text properties of groups of labels at a time, e.g) All labels that contain `TempID`. The value they are changing to is stored within an array hence `lblTempID.text = CustomerID(counter)`. The problem I am having is that even if I get the name of all labels within the table that contain `TempID` and store them in an array I then can't use the `.text` method as it is not a property of a string. Other solutions I have tried have just resulted in all labels being  white rectangles when the form loads...

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you need to put the controls in an container.

```
var labControls = new List<Label>();
labControls.Add(TempID1);
labControls.Add(TempID2);
labControls.Add(TempID3);
....
foreach(var lab in labControls)
{
     lab.Text = "new text";
}
```

Comment: I dont understand what this does? Forgive me for my lack of knowledge, I have been coding for less than a few months

Comment: it puts the labels into a container. You can then access them in a loop or by index - `labControls[0]` is the first one in the list

Comment: Thankyou sir, I shall try this!

Comment: This solution actually gives you another task when adding a new label to the form in the future: you must also remember to add the control to the List. @VisualVincent posted the best solution which will automatically find all the controls which match the name dynamically. (Mine also casts as Labels :) but may be a little over complex).

Comment: Yes, this is simpler but manual. I felt the other solutions disguised the essence of what was going on, too much magic. I suggest that once you understand the fundamental idea then maybe change to use the magic ways of loading the container

Comment: @pm100 I would think that answers shouldn't be given in another language, however similar they are. The OP in a comment above said that they have only been coding for a short while, and in any case, knowledge of another language or how to convert the code shouldn't be assumed.

Comment: @DavidWilson yup - I didnt notice the vb.net tag. I simply saw a Winforms question. Notice however that OP tagged this as the answer - so he wasnt that confused

Answer (score 1):

Use Linq to get labels by name

```
' say all the labels are directly on the form
' alternatively this could be a Panel, GroupBox, etc.
Dim container As Control = Me
' get all Labels in the container
Dim myLabels As IEnumerable(Of Label) = container.Controls.OfType(Of Label)
' get all labels with "TempID" in their name
Dim myLabelTempIDs As IEnumerable(Of Label) = myLabels.Where(Function(l) l.Name.Contains("TempID"))
' get the only label named exactly "lblTempID1"
Dim myLabelTempID1 As Label = myLabels.Where(Function(l) l.Name = "lblTempID1").Single()

For counter As Integer = 1 To 10
    Dim counterLocal = counter
    Dim myLabelTempID = myLabels.Where(Function(l) l.Name = $"lblTempID{counterLocal}").Single()
    myLabelTempID.Text = CustomerID(counter)
Next
```

With extension method

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' get all Labels in Me, using extension method defined below
        Dim myLabels As IEnumerable(Of Label) = Me.ChildControls(Of Label)

        For counter As Integer = 1 To 10
            Dim counterLocal = counter
            Dim myLabelTempID = myLabels.Where(Function(l) l.Name = $"lblTempID{counterLocal}").Single()
            myLabelTempID.Text = CustomerID(counter)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class

Public Module extensions

    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function ChildControls(Of T As Control)(ByVal parent As Control) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        Dim result As New List(Of T)
        For Each ctrl As Control In parent.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is T Then result.Add(CType(ctrl, T))
            result.AddRange(ctrl.ChildControls(Of T)())
        Next
        Return result
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: I understand it all besides the last line, how would I assign each individual labels text property as they are all going to be different?

Comment: Do you have anything which corresponds to the suffix on the label (I assume there is a suffix)?

Comment: Yes they all have 'TempID' but are each followed by an Integer. TempID1, TempID2, etc..

Comment: Which version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: I am on visual studio 2017

Comment: I'd suggest using an extension method I added to my answer. It allows you to access all labels, regardless of being in containers, recursively.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't see why the others are making this so complicated (no offense, but it's true).

Using a [**`For` loop**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement) and [**`Me.Controls.Find()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) (`Me` being the current form) you can quite easily access sequentially named labels.

```
'Assuming you have 50 labels:
For i = 1 To 50
    Dim FoundControls As Control() = Me.Controls.Find("lblTempID" & i, True) 'Find the label with the name "lblTempID#" - where # is the current index (1-50).
    If FoundControls.Count > 0 Then 'Was a label found?
        FoundControls(0).Text = CustomerID(i) 'Change its text.
    End If
Next
```

This will look for the labels recursively (meaning it'll look for them even in child containers such as panels and group boxes) and change the text of the ones it finds.

The only backside is if you have multiple labels with the exact same name, but in different containers, then this will only change the text of the first one it finds. So as long as your labels have unique names this should work fine.

Comment: Much simpler than my answer. Nice

Comment: Cheers, I didn't think about using recursion

Comment: @Visual Vincent The problem is solved but I am presented with a new one at hand. All controls, appear as white rectangles that seem to jitter/blink, refreshing the form shows them properly but I am unable to press any buttons/interact with the form.

Comment: @djv : You've got a very nice solution as well. It's neat and rather flexible, though perhaps a bit complicated in the eyes of newer coders? ;)

Comment: @Tom : Where/how often are you updating these exactly? (i.e. where are you running my code?)

Comment: @Visual Vincent I am running it within a TableLayoutPanel_paint, basically as soon as the form loads. I am also having issue with the .Find extension as it throws an error stating that 'Argument not specified for parameter 'searchAllChildren' of Public overloads Function ... '

Comment: @Tom : Running this in the `Paint` event is a **really** bad idea since it fires irregularly (it can fire continuously all the time, it can fire a few times a minute, or it can fire once during the lifetime of the app, etc...). You never know when the `Paint` event will be raised the next time, so you shouldn't use it for updates other than to perform custom drawing routines. _**Instead**_ you should only run this when the data actually needs to be updated.

Comment: @Tom : As for the error you're receiving: Have you made sure that you aren't missing anything in the code, if you compare it to mine?

Comment: @ Visual Vincent I am positive but I have managed to form my own solution but I cannot share as it goes over the char limit

Comment: @Tom : So write it in an answer instead (there's an answer box in the bottom of the page). Posting solutions is what answers are for. :)

Comment: @Tom : For future reference, you get that error if you've left out the last parameter of `Me.Controls.Find()`. It should be `Me.Controls.Find(<name here>, True)` (notice `True` on the end) - where `<name here>` is the name of the control you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Dim LabelControls = New List(Of Label)
    LabelControls.Add(lblTempID1)
    LabelControls.Add(lblTempID2)
    LabelControls.Add(lblTempID3)
    LabelControls.Add(lblTempID4)
    LabelControls.Add(lblTempID5)
    LabelControls.Add(lblTempID6)
    LabelControls.Add(lblTempID7)
    LabelControls.Add(lblTempID8)
    LabelControls.Add(lblTempID9)
    LabelControls.Add(lblTempID10)  

 For Each label In LabelControls
        If label.Name.Contains("lblTempID") Then
            For counter = 0 To 9
                LabelControls(counter).Text = CStr(TempCustomerID(counter))
            Next
```

It is very similar (If not identical) to a previous answer but it does what I need it to do as of now.

Comment: Nice that you found your own solution, however there are a few things to point out: **1)** You don't need to check the name of each label since you are only adding `lblTempID` labels to the list. **2)** Skip the first `For Each label In LabelControls` loop. Currently, because you have two loops, you are iterating the labels 10^10 times. **3)** Change your loop to: `For counter = 0 To LabelControls.Count - 1` so it will adapt to the amount of labels in the list (makes it easier to add/remove labels in the future). -- Happy coding! ;)